# PHP: Delete Value of variable after 5 min

Tags: php, pdf

I have problem in print PDF from forms.

When new user go to my site and fill the forms and click submit to send data, i need to get this data in PDF file, So i can get the data for this user from :-

```
$lastid = mysql_insert_id();
```

But this i think is not good, When any other user go in this form and click print PDF, he get the last id.

So what can i do to delete the last id and cannot print any data for any user else have fill forms ??

Comment: Are you bothering about [Is mysql_insert_id safe to use?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069806/is-mysql-insert-id-safe-to-use)

Comment: there is no way some other user would get a valid ID with that.

Comment: Design a solution that doesn't require the last insert id.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are getting data into $lastid because of mysql query execution if that so your query will be executed every time and the result will change depending upon users and their requirement.

But if you still want to do so you can use unset() function of php.

unset() destroys the specified variables. The behavior of unset() inside of a function can vary depending on what type of variable you are attempting to destroy. If a globalized variable is unset() inside of a function, only the local variable is destroyed. The variable in the calling environment will retain the same value as before unset() was called.

To unset() a global variable inside of a function, then use the $GLOBALS array to do so:

```
<?php
function foo() 
{
unset($GLOBALS['bar']);
}

$bar = "something";
foo();
?>
```

Complete documentation can be found over [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php)

Comment: mmm its not good with me, because when use `unset` after `$lastid` its delete the value, and user cannot print PDF because `$lastid` was delete

Comment: You said you want to delete the content of your variable after five minutes so you should create a function which will call unset function after five minutes till then your variable will have the value.

Comment: You can check this post to be able to understand http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333434/how-to-call-a-function-in-php-after-10-seconds-of-the-page-load-not-using-html