# Insert a new record in MySQL while adding ID+1 in a different field if the value of the field is null

Tags: php, mysql, sql, triggers, database-trigger

I am modifying my program to allow users to define a customary code for their records in one of my tables in database. So, I'm adding a new column to my database to keep the "local code" of each item defined by the user, as opposed to the "universal code" of the item which is in fact the ID of the record in my table.

So, I want to write a SQL query that while it's inserting a new record, if 'local_code' is null (I can determine this by PHP, but I'm open to SQL solutions for this as well), it inserts the ID of the item in 'local_code'. Something like this:

```
INSERT INTO items (`field_1`, `local_code`, `field_2`, ...)
VALUES ('blah blah blah', PREVIOUS_RECORD_ID + 1, 'blah blah blah', ...);
```

So, basically, my question is how to find PREVIOUS_RECORD_ID without concurrency issues. I can't use LAST_INSERT_ID() here and using SELECT max(id) FROM items can cause concurrency issues if two users add new records simultaneously.

If anyone can come up with a solution using MySQL triggers (like a trigger that updates `local_code` if it's null after inserting a new record), that'll be fine too.

Thanks in advance.

**Example:**

Let's say my database has three columns: id, code, name

```
id   | code | name
 1    AAA     blah blah blah1
 2    BBB     blah blah blah2
```

Now I want to insert a new record. If user has not entered a code, I want my SQL query to do this

```
INSERT INTO items (`code`, `name`)
VALUES (3, 'blah blah blah3', ...);
```

But if the user has entered "CCC" for code, it should work as follows:

```
INSERT INTO items (`code`, `name`)
VALUES ("CCC", 'blah blah blah3', ...);
```

I can determine whether code is null or not using PHP to determine which SQL query should be run. So, my real problem is with the first case when code is NULL. Also, if someone has a SQL solution that handles both cases, that'll be amazing.

Comment: Please provide sample example with data to understand the requirement clearly.

Comment: @SureshGajera Feel free to ask what you think is not clear. I will edit my post and add it. My question is how to get PREVIOUS_RECORD_ID in MySQL without concurrency issues.

Comment: I can't get my head around previous_record_id sample data would help.

Comment: @P.Salmon I just added an example of what I want to do. Is it better now?

Comment: I don't understand why you'd enter '3' under code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my understanding:

1. We are concerned with 2 columns, I name them universal_code and local_code
2. universal_code is an auto_increment and will always be previous_insert + 1
3. When a user will submit data

`universal_code = auto_increment
if local_code is not null
   local_code = submitted local_code value
else
   local_code should be same as universal_code`

What I would do:

**Make this operation with two queries to avoid concurrency issues. Insert then update**

1. Insert row with blank local_code and return newly inserted universal_code
2. Check local_code. If local_code was null, update row with universal_code, else update row with submitted local_code value

Comment: Yes. You are right about what I want to do (+1) but I don't see how this avoids concurrency issues. In fact I had already considered your solution but imagine this: I add a new record, let's say id=3, someone else simultaneously inserts another record, i.e. id=4, then when I run update, it inserts 4 in the record associated with ID=3 which is bad. And I'm running two queries. I prefer to do it one query only if possible.

Comment: The point is that you will always run an update on the id that your insert query will return.

So if you add a record with id=3, your insert will return id 3.
Then your update will be `update table set local_code = 3 where universal_code = 3`. You will not be concerned/clash with id=4

Comment: How's that supposed to happen? The whole point of my question is to get the ID correctly. I can't use LAST_INSERT_ID() because I am not using one connection per each query in my design. How can I get the id that my insert query returns? Write the SQL code please. That's where I'm lost.

Comment: See this answer if you are still concerned with concurrency. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069806/is-mysql-insert-id-safe-to-use)